# Black screen with GLUT?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glut, volume

I am trying to do some volume rendering based on [this code](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/352270/Getting-started-with-Volume-Rendering).

What I am doing right now is that I have some sample 3D data (the array chBuffer is essentially a 4*4*4 test data array) and I am converting that into an OpenGL 3D Texture. After that, I am attempting to render this texture using other OpenGL commands. However, when I run the application, the screen is completely black with something showing up. Is there anything specific I am doing wrong that should fix this problem?

Here's my code:

```
#include <glut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <gl/glext.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
GLfloat dOrthoSize = 1.0f;
GLuint mu3DTex;
#define MAP_3DTEXT( TexIndex ) \
    glTexCoord3f(0.0f, 0.0f, ((float)TexIndex+1.0f)/2.0f);  \
    glVertex3f(-dOrthoSize,-dOrthoSize,TexIndex);\
    glTexCoord3f(1.0f, 0.0f, ((float)TexIndex+1.0f)/2.0f);  \
    glVertex3f(dOrthoSize,-dOrthoSize,TexIndex);\
    glTexCoord3f(1.0f, 1.0f, ((float)TexIndex+1.0f)/2.0f);  \
    glVertex3f(dOrthoSize,dOrthoSize,TexIndex);\
    glTexCoord3f(0.0f, 1.0f, ((float)TexIndex+1.0f)/2.0f);  \
    glVertex3f(-dOrthoSize,dOrthoSize,TexIndex);
void main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutCreateWindow("Name");


    char* chBuffer = new char[64];
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
        chBuffer[i] = ((i + (i / 8)) % 2) * 128 + 127;


    char* chRGBABuffer = new char[256];
    glGenTextures(1, (GLuint*)&mu3DTex);



    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, mu3DTex);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);



    for (int nIndx = 0; nIndx < 64; ++nIndx)
    {
        chRGBABuffer[nIndx * 4] = chBuffer[nIndx];
        chRGBABuffer[nIndx * 4 + 1] = chBuffer[nIndx];
        chRGBABuffer[nIndx * 4 + 2] = chBuffer[nIndx];
        chRGBABuffer[nIndx * 4 + 3] = chBuffer[nIndx];
    }

    glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGBA, 4, 4, 4, 0,
        GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid *)chRGBABuffer);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
    glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER, 0.03f);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
    glLoadIdentity();


    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_3D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, mu3DTex);

    for (float fIndx = -1.0f; fIndx <= 1.0f; fIndx += 0.003f)
    {
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        MAP_3DTEXT(fIndx);
        glEnd();
    }
    system("pause");


}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is 100% not how to use GLUT.

You need to:

1. Set a `glutDisplayFunc()` callback
2. Call `glFlush()` at the end of it
3. Call `glutMainLoop()` in `main()` instead of throwing GL commands at the wall and hoping for the best

Something like this (untested):

```
#include <glut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

GLfloat dOrthoSize = 1.0f;

#define MAP_3DTEXT( TexIndex ) \
    glTexCoord3f(0.0f, 0.0f, ((float)TexIndex+1.0f)/2.0f);  \
    glVertex3f(-dOrthoSize,-dOrthoSize,TexIndex);\
    glTexCoord3f(1.0f, 0.0f, ((float)TexIndex+1.0f)/2.0f);  \
    glVertex3f(dOrthoSize,-dOrthoSize,TexIndex);\
    glTexCoord3f(1.0f, 1.0f, ((float)TexIndex+1.0f)/2.0f);  \
    glVertex3f(dOrthoSize,dOrthoSize,TexIndex);\
    glTexCoord3f(0.0f, 1.0f, ((float)TexIndex+1.0f)/2.0f);  \
    glVertex3f(-dOrthoSize,dOrthoSize,TexIndex);

GLuint mu3DTex;
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
    glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER, 0.03f);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_3D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, mu3DTex);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    for (float fIndx = -1.0f; fIndx <= 1.0f; fIndx += 0.003f)
    {
        MAP_3DTEXT(fIndx);
    }
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutCreateWindow("Name");

    char* chBuffer = new char[64];
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
        chBuffer[i] = ((i + (i / 8)) % 2) * 128 + 127;

    char* chRGBABuffer = new char[256];
    glGenTextures(1, (GLuint*)&mu3DTex);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, mu3DTex);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    for (int nIndx = 0; nIndx < 64; ++nIndx)
    {
        chRGBABuffer[nIndx * 4] = chBuffer[nIndx];
        chRGBABuffer[nIndx * 4 + 1] = chBuffer[nIndx];
        chRGBABuffer[nIndx * 4 + 2] = chBuffer[nIndx];
        chRGBABuffer[nIndx * 4 + 3] = chBuffer[nIndx];
    }

    glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGBA, 4, 4, 4, 0,
        GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid *)chRGBABuffer);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0);

    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, this worked. I'm going to look at some more GLUT tutorials before jumping back into this.